# Calories in (cooked) pasta

Tags: pasta, nutrient-composition, calories

I bought a 500g pack of Tesco penne pasta recently – https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/products/254878482

As you can see on the website, it states that 100g of the pasta contains around 176 calories.

But after cooking the pasta, I noticed it weighed a lot more. I found that around 1/6 of the pack weighed around 225g instead of the 80 or so grams that I was expecting.

So when the packet states the nutritional information for 100g of the pasta, is it referring to *cooked* or *uncooked* pasta?

I imagine it is referring to 100g of cooked pasta... I'm hoping that's the case anyway, I want as many calories as possible.

Comment: See this, I assume it is the same for most pasta : https://www.barilla.com/en-us/help/nutrition-related-questions/nutritional-information-cooked-or-uncooked-pasta

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best way to be confident is to check some clear nutrition facts directly.

The USDA reports that ["Pasta, dry, unenriched"](https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/fdc-app.html#/food-details/168928/nutrients) has 371 calories per 100g, and ["Pasta, cooked, unenriched, without added salt"](https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/fdc-app.html#/food-details/168928/nutrients) has 158 calories per 100g.

So your 176 calories per 100g seems to be for cooked pasta; it's *way* too few calories for 100g dry, even if your pasta is slightly different from the USDA's default.

Calories per gram when cooked is going to vary a bit, because if you cook it a bit more or less, it'll take on a bit more or less water. So the same amount of dry pasta, with the same amount of calories, may weigh slightly different amounts.

Also, I looked at the page you linked. Down at the bottom it says:

> When cooked according to instructions. 75g of uncooked pasta weighs approximately 170g when cooked.

And indeed, along with per 100g nutrition facts, it has a per 170g column. So yes, it appears that those nutrition facts are for cooked pasta.

Comment: Great research and conclusion! Makes perfect sense!